# android update sdk --no-ui:making it selective

Tags: android, sdk, ubuntu-14.04, headless

I am in the process of setting up a headless Ubuntu server to experiment with [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).  My first attempt was on a virtual server with 15Gb of disk space.  It came a cropper because I ran out of disk space during the `android update sdk --no-ui` step.  I was slightly taken aback at this but I decided to try again with a server with 20Gb of disk space.  Much to my surprise it consumed all of the 20Gb and gave up.

Clearly, this is not a viable route forward.  I could in principle get a VM with, say, a 100Gb disk but I would end up paying for something I don't need.  I observed what was happening during the install more carefully during my second attempt.  The `android update sdk` command gets a whole load of SDK APIs and the corresponding documentation all the way down to the distant Android Version 1 days.

I have no interest whatsoever in being able to compile APKs for anything lower than, say, Android 4.x.  I have checked the docs but been unable to find any mechanism for instructing `android update sdk` to be more specific in what it downloads.

The closest I have come to finding something useful is

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter android-XX > /dev/null
```

which I suspect sends the `android-XX` version to `/dev/null` oblivion.  However, it is not clear to me how/whether I can filter out everything less than, say, android-43.

I suspect this is possible but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I am also having same issue did you got any solution ? bty how to remove unnecessary Android versions ?

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out on my own eventually so I thought I would share it here for the benefit of anyone running into this thread.

The right way to do this to selectively install specified versions of the API is

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter platform-tools,android-XX,android-YY...
```

where `android-XX`, `android-YY` are the versions of the API you want to have installed.  You can establish the relevant numbers from the [Android Documentation](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html).